# a script using "status" as a property name appears to be broken for some browsers, which ones?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I have some JavaScript code like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.example.com/",
  data: {id: 27, status: "ok"}
});
```

In my IDE I see some syntax highlighting around "status", and some sites suggest it should not be used as an identifier, but the code works in all the browsers I have tried.

I suspect this may be a problem with one of the latest generation of browsers, and would like help to identify which one(s).